# Communicate two child fork processes with FIFO

Tags: c, linux

I made this program with pipes to communicate two processes with `PIPES`. Now what I have to do is the same but with `FIFO`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int e, p[20], hijo1, hijo2, nbytes, readbytes;
    char texto[200], readbuffer[100];

    printf("Write the message to send to the other process\n");
    fgets(texto, 100, stdin);

    pipe(p);
    if ((hijo1 = fork()) == -1)
    {
        printf("ERROR FORK\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (hijo1 == 0)
    {
        printf("Im %d  and Im child 1\n", getpid());
        close(p[0]); 

        write(p[1], texto, strlen(texto + 1));
        close(p[1]);
        exit(0);
    }
    if ((hijo2 = fork()) == -1)
    {
        printf("ERROR FORK\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (hijo2 == 0)
    {
        printf("Im %d And Im child 2 \n", getpid());
        close(p[1]);

        write(1, "message received: ", 24);
        while ((nbytes = read(p[0], readbuffer, 8)) == 8)
        {
            write(1, readbuffer, nbytes);
        }
        write(1, readbuffer, nbytes);
        printf("\n");
        close(p[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("Im %d and Im the father\n", getpid());
    waitpid(hijo1, &e, 0);
    waitpid(hijo2, &e, 0);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    
}
```

This is what I tried to do but with FIFO

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
   char texto[200], buf[200];
   int fd, fd2, hijo1, hijo2, nbytes;
   printf("Ingrese el mensaje para enviar al FIFO\n");
   fgets(texto, 100, stdin);

   printf("soy %d y soy el padre \n", getpid());
   mkfifo("/tmp/mi_fifo", 0666);

   if ((hijo1 = fork()) == -1)
   {
      printf("ERROR FORK\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   if (hijo1 == 0)
   {
      printf("soy %d y soy el hijo 1 \n", getpid());

      fd = open("/tmp/mi_fifo", O_WRONLY);
      write(fd, texto, sizeof(texto + 1));
      close(fd);
      exit(0);
   }
   if ((hijo2 = fork()) == -1)
   {
      printf("ERROR FORK\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   if (hijo2 == 0)
   {
      printf("soy %d y soy el hijo 2 \n", getpid());
      fd2 = open("/tmp/mi_fifo", O_RDONLY);

      write(1, "el mensaje recibido es: \n", 24);
      while (nbytes = read(fd2, buf, 8) == 8)
      {
         write(1, buf, nbytes);
      }
      write(1, buf, nbytes);

      close(fd2);
      exit(0);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

This Fifo program is not receiving the Message from the other child process. When I print the `buf` variable with `Write()` It shows only one letter. It should show the whole message that's why it is in a while loop. How can I do that? I haven't found any information about fork processes and FIfOs I hope you can help me.

Comment: Please note that you have not asked a question nor described a specific problem.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I have added the problem now

Comment: `sizeof(texto + 1)` not sure what you are trying to do there. Why are you adding 1 to the **array**? Maybe you meant to add 1 to the size. But even that would be wrong. You can't write more than what is in the buffer. It should instead be `strlen(texto)+1`.

Comment: `while (nbytes = read(fd2, buf, 8) == 8)` needs to be `while ((nbytes = read(fd2, buf, 8)) == 8)`. Because `==` has higher precedence than `=`. What you have assigns either 1 or 0 (boolean result) to `nbytes`.

Comment: Thank you very much that worked! You can copy the comments to make a response so I can mark it as correct if you'd like to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least two problems:

1. `sizeof(texto + 1)` needs to be `strlen(texto)+1` to ensure the right size for the string in the buffer.
2. while `(nbytes = read(fd2, buf, 8) == 8)` needs to be while `((nbytes = read(fd2, buf, 8)) == 8)`. Because `==` has higher precedence than `=`. What you have assigns either 1 or 0 (boolean result) to `nbytes`.

Comment: It should probably be `strlen(texto)`. With the `+1`, sender will add 0x00 at the end. Depending on the protocol, this would be fine. But, based on the receiver/parent code, it should be left off because it will read and output the 0x00 to `stdout`